# How to get rid of the "UserWarning: The initializer GlorotUniform is unseeded" message?

Tags: python, keras, mlxtend

I have the following code from:
[Bias-Variance Decomposition for Model Assessment](https://towardsdatascience.com/bias-and-variance-for-model-assessment-a2edb69d09)

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential

from mlxtend.evaluate import bias_variance_decomp
from mlxtend.data import boston_housing_data

from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeRegressor
from sklearn.ensemble import BaggingRegressor
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error

np.random.seed(16)
tf.random.set_seed(16)

X, y = boston_housing_data()
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y,
                                                test_size=0.3,
                                                random_state=123,
                                                shuffle=True)

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(2048, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(512, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(32, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='linear'))

optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam()
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer=optimizer)
model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=100, batch_size=32, verbose=0)
mean_squared_error(model.predict(X_test), y_test)

avg_expected_loss, avg_bias, avg_var = bias_variance_decomp(
    model, X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test, 
    loss='mse',
    num_rounds=100,
    random_seed=16,
    epochs=100,
    batch_size=32,
    verbose=0)

print('Average expected loss: %.3f' % avg_expected_loss)
print('Average bias: %.3f' % avg_bias)
print('Average variance: %.3f' % avg_var)
```

The Code works. However, it produces an annoying warning:

*UserWarning: The initializer GlorotUniform is unseeded and being called multiple times, which will return identical values  each time (even if the initializer is unseeded). Please update your code to provide a seed to the initializer, or avoid using the same initalizer instance more than once.
warnings.warn(*

What changes need to be made to the code in order to get rid of the warning?

Answer (score 1):

As the warning message says, a seed needs to be provided to the initializer. Simply change the code to:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential

from mlxtend.evaluate import bias_variance_decomp
from mlxtend.data import boston_housing_data

from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeRegressor
from sklearn.ensemble import BaggingRegressor
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error

from keras import initializers

np.random.seed(16)
tf.random.set_seed(16)

X, y = boston_housing_data()
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y,
                                                test_size=0.3,
                                                random_state=123,
                                                shuffle=True)

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(2048, activation='relu', 
kernel_initializer=initializers.glorot_uniform(seed=0)))
model.add(Dense(512, activation='relu', 
kernel_initializer=initializers.glorot_uniform(seed=0)))
model.add(Dense(32, activation='relu', 
kernel_initializer=initializers.glorot_uniform(seed=0)))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='linear', 
kernel_initializer=initializers.glorot_uniform(seed=0)))

optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam()
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer=optimizer)
model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=100, batch_size=32, verbose=0)
mean_squared_error(model.predict(X_test), y_test)

avg_expected_loss, avg_bias, avg_var = bias_variance_decomp(
    model, X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test, 
    loss='mse',
    num_rounds=10,
    random_seed=16,
    epochs=10,
    batch_size=32,
    verbose=0)

print('Average expected loss: %.3f' % avg_expected_loss)
print('Average bias: %.3f' % avg_bias)
print('Average variance: %.3f' % avg_var)
```

Comment: The values returned by the initializer are also identical in subsequent calls in case you set the seed.

Comment: Do you need to instantiate a different initializer for each layer? 
Or can you instantiate just one, and use it several times, with different seeds?